No ble module shown on bettercap in Ubuntu
No ble module shown on bettercap
I installed bettercap via apt with the command sudo apt install bettercap, once I run sudo bettercap and type help, there's no bluetooth module like ble.recon or ble.write shown.
system: Ubuntu 22.04

btw I've asked the same question on stack overflow and got the following reply:
As your question is off-topic here at [Stack Overflow], your question is much more appropriate to Ask Ubuntu –
Risto


Ask thr packaging system which packages mention ble with apt-cache search ble;apt-cache search bluetooth.
